# Files retrieved from SQL server FILETABLE are corrupted

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a FILETABLE on SQL Server 2014 with all the default options with a view for retrieving data and stored procedures for inserting and deleting files. Please note that non-transactional access is not enabled on the database because the files shouldn't be visible on the file system.

The problem is that when I retrieve a file from the table and write it to disk, it isn't identical to the original and can't be opened with the associated program.

Code for the view:

```
SELECT stream_id, file_stream, name, CAST(creation_time AS DateTime) AS DateCreated, CAST(last_write_time AS DateTime) AS DateUpdated FROM dbo.DocumentFiles
```

Code for the insert procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DocumentFiles_create]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@name nvarchar(255),
@data varbinary(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier;
set @id = NEWID();
insert into DocumentFiles (stream_id, file_stream, name) VALUES(@id, @data, @name);
select @id;
END
```

Code used for reading:

```
DocumentFile result = null;
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from DocumentView where stream_id = @id", conn);
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result = new DocumentFile();
                    result.stream_id = (Guid)reader["stream_id"];
                    result.file_stream = (byte[])reader["file_stream"];
                    result.name = reader["name"].ToString();
                    result.DateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateCreated"]);
                    result.DateUpdated = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateUpdated"]);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return result;
```

Code used for inserting:

```
public Guid? Insert(DocumentFile obj)
        {
            Guid? result = null;
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_DocumentFiles_create", conn);
            comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", obj.name));
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", obj.file_stream));
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                result = comm.ExecuteScalar() as Guid?;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

The only files that I managed to insert and retrieve intact are image files. I tried using various ms office documents (.doc, .docx, .pptx, etc) as well as archives (rar, zip).

Comment: Running with exception handling disabled may prove insightful, as would looking at the content differences between the input/output files in a hex editor.

Comment: Slight detour...you might want to read this before you continue using the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: You also really should wrap your command and connection objects in a USING statement so they will always be properly disposed of.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and suggestions. I have checked the files in a hex editor and I saw the differences, but I don't know how I can interpret them.